# How to process Dicom Images for CNN?

Tags: cnn, image-preprocessing

I am building a disease classifier. I have Dicom scans for many patients.
The scans have different slice thickness, and different scans have different number of slices. However, the slice thickness for a single patient's scan has the same thickness for all slices.

For example:

Patient1's scan : 100 slices of 2mm thickness

Patient2's scan : 500 slices of 1mm thichness

The number of pixels for each slice is 512 x 512,
so currently the shape of nd array containing the information for

Patient1 is 100*512*512

Patient2 is 500*512*512

I want to pass all patients information into a CNN.
Do I need to resample the slices and make it uniform for all patients (like **512*512*n**). If yes, how to do it, and what should be the value of 'n'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use **zero padding**? It's a pre-processing technique for CNNs, it consists in creating a frame of zeros around the image, so that all input image will have the same size.

The CNN will then learn autonomously to ignore the zeros. It's a common technique, Keras layers already have padding built-in arguments.

Comment: Thank you. Yes zero padding can work in this case.

Comment: Since my case is a 3 dimensional case, I have to add 512 * 512 slices filled with zeros to make all the cases of same length in the 3rd dimension. This is running into memory issues. I have tried using the smaller datatype , but still run into error: 
"MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (601, 512, 512) and data type uint16". I have already tried all the suggestions in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type  What can I do to make all the cases of same length, while managing the memory constraints.